# Can't upload any files to the admin dashboard?

Tags: file-upload, file-permissions, varien-file-uploader, file, core-file-storage

for some reason I can't seem to save extension configuration with files attached.

I'm attempting to update the logo for our PDF extension, when I browse for the file and save it confirms it was saved successfully but it hasn't

I've also just purchased Webshopapps premium matrix rates and I've tried to attach the CSV and save and it did the same thing... any ideas?

I assumed it was down to permissions and attempted to fix them via SSH with no luck

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase anyone else runs into this issue, I figured out the issue on my side... file_uploads was set to off in the php configuration, enabling this fixed the issue.